# Деление рисунка на три части

Tags: изображения, css

Решил использовать библиотеку "Scrollplane" для создания красивого скролла. Вообщем, есть один элемент, я могу его изменять при помощи css.

Нужно нацепить на этот объект картинку. Но, если её растянуть - получается не красиво. Как можно ограничившись одним элементом поделить скроллбар на три части? Верх, середина, которая будет повторяться по вертикали, и конец.

Пока сам не придумал как, активно гуглю. Догадок нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div {
   position: relative;
   /* ... */
}

div:before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   /* ... */
}

div:after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   /* ... */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/26Tz8/